# Angular 8 Routing with useHash: true

Tags: angular, angular-router

Currently, `useHash` is set to `true` in the project I am working on and it works just fine as they all contain a `#` e.g. localhost:4200/my-app/#/page1.

Now, I have a requirement wherein I need to catch this certain URI, which does not have the `#`, and point it to a component. I have tried to set a route for this like this one but it doesn't work.

```
{ path: 'pageWithoutHash', component: NewComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix' }
```

Is there a way to match the URI that is not using a `#` even if `useHash` is set to `true`?

Comment: Is `useHash` required for this project? I mean if you remove the `useHash', your problem will be solved

Comment: @Shuvo Unfortunately, yes. I was told the routing does not properly work in production if this is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a route `matcher` to define your custom rules in the `routing.module.ts`:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: (url) => {
       for (let index = 0; index < url.length; index++) {
         if(url[index].startsWith('#')) return url.length ? { consumed: [] } : { consumed: url };
       } 
       return null;
    },
    component: NewComponent
  },
  { path: 'path_1', component: Component_1 },
  { path: 'path_2', component: Component_2 }
];
```

If any segment of the `url` starts with `#`, `NewComponent` will be displayed.

Comment: I have tried a similar approach before but the `#` is not included in the array of `UrlSegment` passed to the method. Only the segments after the `#` are included. For the case where there is no `#`, the `UrlSegment` array is empty.